# how use loop thumbnails slide

Tags: jquery, css

i wanted prev and next clik logoimage is slide left and right. this image is loop...
i want this slide.. http://zeroturnaround.com/

```
<div class="thumbnailgallery" >
  <div class="showrooms clearfix">
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/best-auto.jpg">1</a> 
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/cheap-car.jpg">2</a>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/cosmo.jpg">3</a>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/golden.jpg">4</a>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/ID.jpg">5</a>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/kia.jpg">6</a>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/maxano.jpg">7</a>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/mmm.jpg">8</a>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/nihon.jpg">9</a>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/sakura.jpg">10</a>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/shwe.jpg">11</a>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/symcar.jpg">12</a>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/theingi.jpg">13</a>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/thuhtetpyisone.jpg">14</a>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/uno-korea.jpg">15</a>
    </div><!-- End Showrooms -->
</div> <!-- End items -->
<span  class="arrowleft" id="prev"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></span>
<span  class="arrowright" id="next"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></span>
```

i have this problem ....

[image]

and

[image]

see this website
http://zeroturnaround.com/

how use jquery...

my jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/kyF8u/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all that you want to have is the behavior like the sample page, then very simply, you can just prepend/append the .logo elements on click like this:

```
$('#prev').on('click', function () {
    var last = $('.logo').last();
    last.prependTo('.showrooms');
});
$('#next').on('click', function () {
    var first = $('.logo').first();
    first.appendTo('.showrooms');
});
```

Here's a **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/VJR4G/)**.

P.S. You will have better results (and responsive capable slider), if you set the logos to float left and give the .showrooms a set height inside of a set width.  This will enable you to not have to use the white-space: nowrap, which will produce weird spacing issues.

As I said, the other benefit is that with the .showrooms set to a percentage width, it will now adapt to the window/viewport size nicely.

EDIT:

Added some animation and updated the fiddle.  There are many ways to do this including animating the left position of the element, so you'll have to play around to get exactly the behavior you want.

```
$('#prev').on('click', function () {
    var last = $('.logo').last().css({opacity: '0', width: '0px'});
    last.prependTo('.showrooms');
    last.animate({opacity: '1', width: '108px'});
});
$('#next').on('click', function () {
    var first = $('.logo').first();
    first.animate({opacity: '0', width: '0px'}, function() {
        //this callback only runs after the animation is completed
        //for the next you need to animate out THEN append the item 
        //and reset its css properties:
        first.appendTo('.showrooms').css({opacity: '1', width: '108px'});
    });
});
```

Comment: I made an example for you and updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/VJR4G/

Answer (score 1):

1. Your image size is 70, but you increment/decrement by 100.
2. Remove cloning first and last item, then 15th/1st image are fixed

Comment: yes thanks my friends .. please give me example jfiddle

Comment: thank my freinds but i wanted this example http://zeroturnaround.com/   please your see

Comment: please next give me your example